# Android RecyclerView NotifyDataSetChanged with LiveData

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

When instantiating the `ListAdapter` for my `RecyclerView`, I call:

```
    viewModel.currentList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
        adapter.submitList(it)
    }
```

which is what I've seen done in the Android Sunflower project as the proper way to submit `LiveData` to a `RecyclerView`. This works fine, and when I add items to my database they are updated in the `RecyclerView`. However, if I write

```
    viewModel.currentList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
        adapter.submitList(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Then my adapters data observer always lags behind. I call

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver(){
    override fun onChanged() {
        super.onChanged()
            if (adapter.currentList.isEmpty()) {
                empty_dataset_text_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                empty_dataset_text_view.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
})
```

And `empty_dataset_text_view` appears one change *after* the list size reached zero, and likewise it disappears one change after the list size is non-zero.

Clearly, the observer is running the code before it has submitted `it` which in this case is `LiveData` queried from `Room`. I'd simply like to know what the workaround is for this: is there a way to "await" a return from my LiveData?